# PHP split string to next period (.)

Tags: php

My aim is to split string after every 7 words. If the 7th word has a comma (,), move to the next word with period (.) or exclamation (!)

So far, I've been able to split string by 7 words, but cannot check if it contains commas (,) or move to the next word with . or !

```
   $string = "I have a feeling about the rain, let us ride. He figured I was only joking.";
   $explode = explode(" ", $string);
   $chunk_str = array_chunk($explode, 7);

   for ($x=0; $x<count($chunk_str); $x++)
   {
       $strip = implode(" ",$chunk_str[$x]);
       echo $strip.'<br><br>';
   }
```

I expect

```
I have a feeling about the rain, let us ride.

He figured I was only joking.
```

But the actual output is

```
I have a feeling about the rain,

let us ride. He figured I was

only joking.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do what you want. Iterate through the list of words, 7 at a time. If the 7th word ends with a comma, increase the list pointer until you reach a word ending with a period or exclamation mark (or the end of the string). Output the current chunk. When you reach the end of the string, output any remaining words.

```
$string = "I have a feeling about the rain, let us ride. He figured I was only joking.";
$explode = explode(' ', $string);
$num_words = count($explode);
if ($num_words < 7) {
    echo $string;
}
else {
    $k = 0;
    for ($i = 6; $i < count($explode); $i += 7) {
        if (substr($explode[$i], -1) == ',') {
            while ($i < $num_words && substr($explode[$i], -1) != '.' && substr($explode[$i], -1) != '!') $i++;
        }
        echo implode(' ', array_slice($explode, $k, $i - $k + 1)) . PHP_EOL;
        $k = $i + 1;
    }
}
echo implode(' ', array_slice($explode, $k)) . PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
I have a feeling about the rain, let us ride. 
He figured I was only joking.
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/bkZ6O)

Comment: It worked as expected. What was your thought process like when you wanted to solve this problem. I just couldn't wrap my head around it. How did you think about the solution?

Comment: @ForALLs I worked from your problem description, just looking at the last character  of every 7th word (the `for` loop starts at the 7th word (index `$i = 6`) and looks at every 7th word after we output a chunk (`$i += 7`)). If the last character of the word at that index (`substr($explode[$i], -1)`) is a comma, keep incrementing the index until the last character of a word is a period or an exclamation mark, or we reach the end of the string (`$i == $num_words`). `array_slice` is then the easiest way to extract the portion of the array that represents the string. Hope this helps.

Comment: It did. Thank you once again.